# How can I create a list of all email addresses by Industry?

Tags: custom-reports, reports-folder

I'm just trying to create a list of all names and email addresses for everyone within a given market sector defined by the field Industry.

The standard reports don't offer it, so I am looking for help with just pulling out all the email addresses for all of our customers (tens of thousands in many different market sectors) so we can reach out to them by email.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a new report type you need admin access. If you do not have this, you should contact your admin or developer to create the report for you. It sounds like you are just looking to add fields to an existing report type (Contacts?). If you do have access, follow these steps (different for lightning):

1. Click on **Setup** in the upper right corner next to your name.
2. In the quick find box on the left type **Report Types**
3. Click **Report Types**
4. Under the label column click **Contact** (not edit)
5. In the **Fields Available for Reports** section at the bottom, click **Edit Layout**
6. The list of all fields for on the Contact object are in a pane on the right hand side. You can drag any of these fields into the main area and they will become available in the Contacts report.

If you are looking to use a field on a related object you can do this two ways:

1. Add a formula field to the contact object that looks up value from the related object. Then follow the steps above to add it to the report type.
2. You can create a new report type and use two related objects to create a joined report.

Option 2 is best when creating reports on objects that may have a one-to-many relationship such as Contacts with Cases. You may, for example, want to pull a list of contacts' email addresses only if the contact has an closed case so that you could send them a satisfaction survey about the case. Salesforce allows you to join up to four related objects in a single report type.